# Upper limit when using binary search to find roots.

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm having some trouble grasping how binary searches work.  This actually comes from a programming exercise I'm working on but I want to understand the math, at least as much as I can.

Here is the problem.

```
A * x + B * sqrt(x ^ 3) - C * exp(-x / 50) - D = 0
```

I get that I'm going to be solving for a value of x.    I also understand how a binary search works.  Split range in half, then half again etc.

What I do not understand here is where I'm getting the bounds to actually search for x.

If my input data is as follows ( A, B, C, D) :

```
0.59912051 0.64030348 263.33721367 387.92069617
```

If told to find the square root then I get how that works.

```
x = sqrt(num)

x * x = num
```

So if you use num for x then upper bound to start can be num * num.

I also understand how it would work with a sorted array since you know upper bounds will be the last entry in the array.

I just don't understand this use case, or how to implement it actually.  I assume that once given the upper bound the it's just a matter of running the search unti that equation returns true.

( also sorry if I didn't tag this correctly, I wasn't quite sure. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to solve $f(x) = 0$ for $x$. For that, you need starting points $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ have opposite signs. How to find those will depend on the exact form of $f(x)$...

In your particular case, by inspection $f(0) < 0$, so $x_1 = 0$; need to find a place where it is positive. Bound $-C \mathrm{e}^{-x/50}$ from below by $-C$, notice $\sqrt{x^3} > x$ if $x > 1$ and you are left with:

$\begin{align}
   (A + B) x - (C + D) = 0
\end{align}$

and you have a crude upper bound $x_2 = (C + D) / (A + B)$.

Comment: Actually $\sqrt{x^3}<x$ when $0<x<1$...

Comment: @HenningMakholm, right you are. Thanks.

Comment: @vonbrand Thank you.  I won't even claim to totally understand that but it's what I was looking for.